# C# How to: transform a range from one array to another

Tags: c#, c++

Imagine I've got two arrays of **doulbe** called **A** and **B**.

I want to take a part (range) from the **A**, apply some function to every element in that part and save the results into a part (range) of **B**.

I do know how to implement it with C++ using **std::transform**.

But what for C#?

P.S. The code with C++:

```
double *src = new double[100];
double *dst = new double[24];

std::generate(src,src+100,[]() { return 0.25; } );
std::generate(dst,dst+24,[]() { return 1.0; } );

std::transform(src+12,src+24,dst+12, [](double d) { return d*d*sqrt(d); } );

delete[] src;
delete[] dst;

enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do transformation. Since you are deleting `dst` at the end, and fill it completely during the transformation, it is not necessary to write to an existing array:

```
var src = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => 0.25).ToArray();
var dst = src.Skip(12).Take(12).Select(d => d*d*Math.Sqrt(d)).ToArray();
```

> I have to overwrite only a part of B using only a part of A

If you need to overwrite existing entries, use `CopyTo` method:

```
var src = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => 0.25).ToArray();
var dst = new double[50];
src.Skip(12).Take(12).Select(d => d*d*Math.Sqrt(d)).ToList().CopyTo(dst, 31);
```

Comment: Slightly better than mine because I brain farted and didnt use a Select to fill the original array. lol

Comment: The problem is: the **B** is filled with data I need, I have to overwrite only a part of **B** using only a part of **A**.
I see, how one can extract the range with **Skip** and **Take**. Now, how to overwrite a part of the **dst**, not making a new **dst**?

Comment: I've got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src = new List<double>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                src.Add(0.25D);

            var dst = src.Skip(12).Take(12).Select(d => d * d * Math.Sqrt(d));
        }
    }
}
```

The last line of code is what you were really asking for, Skip will skip the first 12, Take uses the next 12 in, and the Select does the transformation you asked for.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!